# Unexpected output in C programming using scanf() function

Tags: c, scanf

I got an unexpected output in C programming like this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0newD.jpg).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d ",&i);
    scanf("%d ",&j);
    printf("\n%d \n",i);
    printf("%d",j);
}
```

The program seems to take in 3 inputs and displays only the 1st two and i have no clue why. Any ideas ?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us *in* the question itself, as text. And show us the actual as well as the expected output. And perhaps refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) says,

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe how to
> process the sequence of input characters.
>
> A directive is one of the following:
>
> - A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see
>   isspace(3)). **This directive matches any amount of white space,
>   including none, in the input.**
> - ...

Which means any white space characters with directive as `%d<space>` will read a number followed by consuming a sequence of white space characters in the input and only returns until you type a non white space character. That how you are able to provide a number in addition.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space after the "%d" in your code:

```
scanf("%d", &i);
scanf("%d", &j);
```

Comment: Please try to explain *why* this would solve the problem. What does the spaces do that cause problems? And please refresh [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).